# Copy Row Table into 'New Table'. | jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have created a **dataTable copy row**.

`mainTable` can only copy to the `secondTable`.

**The problem is when adding New Table**,

&

**i want the** `mainTable` **row can copy into New Table.**

i already create "`Create New Table`" button

New table will append into parent div `allTable`

[**MY JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/4fukuma/o6ysgzps/).

**Reference :**

> - I want copy row into selected table(secondTable/newTable). not multiple. and I dont know how to add the selected button, because I'm using a variable.
> - I have parent div `class="allTable"` for Table/children (`mainTable`,
>     `secondTable`, and *New Table*).
> - i have "COPY ROW" for copy row table from `mainTable` to another Table, but now only work to copy into the `secondTable`.
> - In the `$(document).ready(function())`,
>     I have created dataTable for `mainTable` and `secondTable`.
> - `mainTable` ID is #table1
> - `secondTable` ID is #table2
> - New Table ID is #newTable + index (newTable(3) )
> - New Table will display blank data.

**SCREENSHOT :**

[image]

**I really hope for your help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works, but you can improve it, I hope you can get the idea from here, this is not fully working as intended but the flow might help you.

https://jsfiddle.net/o6ysgzps/26/ I have updated the fiddle,

as you can see, I collected the list of tables that are created, and looped to each tables with a confirmation box to select which table you want it to be copied to., You can use bootstrap modal and jquery confirm to make it better,

You can make it cleaner,

html

```
 <body>
    <select id='cboList' style=''></select>
      <div class="allTable">

        <div class="one" style="padding-bottom:50px">
          <h2>TABLE 1</h2>
          <table id="table1" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Audience Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>


        <br>
        <button id="Copy">COPY ROW &raquo;</button>
        <!-- <button id="LeftMove" style="float:left;">&laquo; left</button> -->
        <br>

        <h2>TABLE 2</h2>
        <div class="two">
          <table id="table2" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Audience Name</th>
                <th>Type</th>
                <th>Size</th>
                <th>Date Created</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
          </table>
        </div>

        <br>
        <br>
        <br>

        <input type="button" class="submitButton" value="Create New Table">
        <h2>NEW TABLE GOES HERE</h2>

    </div>
    </body>
```

This is the js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var mainTable = $('#table1').dataTable({
    "ajax": "https://api.myjson.com/bins/zvujb",
    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },
      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],
    "scrollY": "200px",

  }); // mainTable 


  var secondTable = $('#table2').dataTable({

    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },

      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],

    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": "true"

  }); // secondTable


  mainTable.on('click', 'tbody tr', function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');
  });

    $('#Copy').on('click', function() {
     var tables = $(".allTable").find("table*[id]").not("#table1");
     tables.each(function(){
          console.log(this.id);
          var tbl_id = this.id; 
          var $elem = $(this);
          var r = confirm("Copy to table "+tbl_id+"?");
          var table_to_copy = $elem.dataTable();
          if (r == true) {
              copyRows(mainTable, table_to_copy);
              alert("Copied!");
          } else {

          }
      });


    //
  });


}); // end of  $(document).ready...



function copyRows(fromTable, toTable) {
  var $row = fromTable.find(".selected");
  $.each($row, function(k, v) {
    if (this !== null) {
      addRow = fromTable.fnGetData(this);
      toTable.fnAddData(addRow); // <-- Copy Row
      // fromTable.fnDeleteRow(this); <-- Move row, delete main row.
    }
  });
}

var tableIndex = 3;
$('.submitButton').click(function() {
      let addIndex = tableIndex++;
      var addTable = '<div class="newTable'+ addIndex +'">' +
        '<table id="newTable'+ addIndex +'" class="table table-bordered table-hover">' +
        '<thead>' +
        '<tr>' +
        '<th></th>' +
        '<th>Audience Name</th>' +
        '<th>Type</th>' +
        '<th>Size</th>' +
        '<th>Date Created</th>' +
        '</tr>' +
        '</thead>' +
        '</table>' +
        '</div>';

    $('.allTable').append(addTable);
    var newTable = $("#newTable"+ addIndex).dataTable({

    "columns": [{
      "data": "id"
    }, {
      "data": "name"
    }, {
      "data": "subtype"
    }, {
      "data": "approximate_count"
    }, {
      "data": "time_created"
    }],
    "columnDefs": [{
      "targets": 0,
      "checkboxes": {
        "selectRow": true
      },

      "render": function(data, type, full, meta) {
        return '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' + $('<div/>').text(data).html() + '">';
      }
    }],

    "scrollY": "200px",
    "scrollCollapse": "true"

  }); // newTable
});
```

Comment: oww thanks, i think.. i need to create button dropdown copy to "tableID", right?

Comment: yes create a modal with a dropdown of tables, an upvote will be highly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

modify your code as follow:

```
function copyRows(fromTable, toTable) {
  var toTable = $("table:last").dataTable(); // add this line to the function. Then you can remove toTable from parameters
```

Comment: Nice, but I want copy row into selected table(secondTable/newTable). not multiple. and I dont know how to add the selected button, because I'm using a variable.

Comment: this is a problem. `$('#Copy').on('click', function() {copyRows(mainTable, secondTable);});`

Comment: you wrote: "i want the mainTable row can copy into New Table.". My script will get last table (which is new) and copy there.

Comment: explain, what exactly you need from script? to select table, then copy rows there? or just put rows in the new table?

Comment: to select row from mainTable, then copy to selected table.